# Closure of intersection of cone and affine space

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-cone

Let $\mathcal{K}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex cone and let $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be an affine space such that $\mathcal{K}\cap\mathcal{A}\neq\emptyset$. Is it necessarily true that 
$$
\overline{\mathcal{K}\cap\mathcal{A}} = \overline{\mathcal{K}}\cap\mathcal{A}?
$$
(Here $\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of a set $A$.)

Since any affine space $\mathcal{A}$ is closed, the containment $\overline{\mathcal{K}\cap\mathcal{A}} \subseteq \overline{\mathcal{K}}\cap\mathcal{A}$ is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

No. Take
$$
K = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid z > 0 \text{ or } (z = 0 \text{ and } x = 0)\}$$
together with
$$
A = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid z = 0\}.$$

Comment: You can construct a similar example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by omitting the $y$ component.